# Plotting a function with Bessel zeroes and Bessel functions

Tags: plotting

I have the given function that I would like to plot:

\begin{equation}
u(r,\theta)=-\frac{2}{R\Theta Y_{n}\alpha_{n,k}}J_{n}\bigg(\frac{\alpha_{n,k}}{R}r\bigg)\sin\frac{n\pi}{\alpha}\theta
\end{equation}

where $R=1, \Theta=2\pi, \alpha=\pi$ and $\theta$ and $r$ are variables.

But the problem is to use the Bessel zero, the Bessel J and Bessel Y expressions  correctly

I tried to write the Bessel zero of the second kind, Y

\begin{equation}
Y_n\alpha_{n,k}
\end{equation}

as:

```
 [BesselYZero[0, 1]]
```

Note that $Y_n$ is similar to $\cos(n)$, just that it is a Bessel function of the second kind of the **integer** *n*.
Then over to $\alpha_{n,k}$. These are the [Bessel zeros](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi0sZG4r_H5AhUyx4UKHXXbDVMQFnoECB4QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FBesselFunctionZeros.html&usg=AOvVaw1U-zmjtpjXYg41Ze_jwcvz). The equivalent zeroes for $\cos$ are $n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ (as an example).

So the version of cosine would be:

```
Cos[Sum[n, {x, 0, k}]] (n Pi + Pi/2)
```

But how to write the Bessel of second kind version of this?

Then I write  the Bessel function, J:

\begin{equation}
J_n\bigg(\frac{\alpha_{n,k}}{R}r\bigg)
\end{equation}

```
besselj[besselJzero[0,1],r]
```

and then the whole expression as:

```
(2/(2 Pi (BesselYZero[0, 1]))) BesselJ[BesselJZero[0, 1], r] Sin[n θ]
```

But plotting it seems impossible, and it may be even wrongly written compared to the original formula.

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: What it $\alpha_{n,k}$ in your formula? Below you write $\alpha=\pi$. How to understand this?

Comment: It is better to include this information in your post. Not everyone reads all comments. By the way, it is quite unusual to use the notation $Y_n\alpha_{n,k}$ for zeroes of $Y_n$

Comment: For me `Plot[(2/(2 Pi (BesselYZero[0, 1]))) BesselJ[BesselJZero[0, 1], r], {r,0, 10}]` works. `Sin[n θ]` is just a constant that you need to specify.

Comment: Since your function seems to depend on 2 arguments, $r$ and $\Phi$. you should use `Plot3D`

Comment: Yes, that didn't work either.